# Некрасивое отображение матрицы

Tags: python, list, матрицы

Я преобразую список из 24 элементов в матрицу 4x6 с помощью reshape.

Так выглядит результат.
Вопрос, почему третья строка так отобразилась?

```
[ 72 233  33 109]
[ 56 255  33  24]
[60 24 72 59]
[ 77 229  59   0]
[255 108 109   0]
[ 77  60 108 233]
```

Нужно вот так :

```
[ 72 233  33 109]
[ 56 255  33  24]
[ 60 24   72  59]
[ 77 229  59   0]
[255 108 109   0]
[ 77  60 108 233]
```

Comment: pprint?????????

Comment: Ух ты, первый раз вижу, спасибо

Comment: Нет, все же вопрос открыт. Я заполняю матрицу таким образом : `matrix = np.array(saveGrid).reshape(6, 4)`
    `matrix_as_list = matrix.tolist()`
   `for row in matrix:`
      `print(row)`

Comment: Как тут использовать pprint?

Comment: Или может есть другие способы?

Comment: у вас matrix - numpy.array? почему просто не сделать `print(matrix)` 
 или `print(np.array_str(matrix))`?

Comment: `[[255 233  77 108]
 [ 60  59  24  59]
 [233  33 229   0]
 [ 77   0  72  60]
 [ 72 255 109  33]
 [229 109  24 108]]`   Все это делалось чтобы убрать вот эти двойные квадратные скобки

Comment: Но так все же лучше, оставлю так, спасибо за ответ

Comment: Третья строка так отобразилась, потому что она единственная, в которой нет трёхзначных чисел. Я уже захожу на второй ваш вопрос, и не понимаю, что вы хотите сделать? Если вы выводите цвета на матрицу, то зачем делать вывод как на матрицу в программе?

Comment: Я вывожу цвета в список, а список преобразую в матрицу.